# node.js How to functions return variable to router

Tags: javascript, node.js

sorry for my dumb question but I'm new in node.js and i searched a lot of verbals in google and I don't find anything that matches my problem :( Ok, so my problem is that I have function that counts entries from mongodb like this

```
KRS.count({}, function (err,c) {
req.flash('count', c);
});
```

previously i used callback like this

```
var count = otherFile.count(function(err, count){
       if(err){throw err;}
       else{
         res.render('home', { count: count, user: req.user });
      }
    });
```

and this works but I need to get two or more functions result so this method is useless. I searched that connect-flash can easly assign variable to call it via count = req.flash('message') but only examples that I see on the internet was using req.flash('message', variable) in app.get and then redirects :/ So question is how I can pass variable from function in other file to router without callback(because it can only give one variable like on above example). Thank you in advice. Regards :)

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take at tour at https://stackoverflow.com/tour

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way would be:

```
KRS.count({}, function (err,count1) {

    otherFile.count(function(err, count2){

        res.render('home', { count1: count1, count2: count2, user: req.user });

    }); 

});
```

but you can also use:

- Promises
- async/await

unfortunately i don't use that myself so can't show you how to use it.